# how can i use two diffrent string value with same name in String.xml?

Tags: java, android

I want to have two kind of message types for example ironic and official. When user selected ironic all message show in ironic way and when user select official all messages show in official way. i want to do it with two string value type with same name but different value in String.xml. I want to select which type will be used in program when app run. Are there any other way to do that. 
thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't give same name of two strings with different value inside string.xml, do it via programmatically if you want to do runtime,,,

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have 2 different strings with same key or name in string.xml

you can probably make app_name and app_name_1 for ironic and official and whenever official just append _1 to string

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you are speaking about 2 languages "ironic" and "official".
Android allows custom languages. So just create 2 different string files in 2 different resource directories, something like values-irn/strings.xml and values-off/strings.xml.

Then in your onCreate() of the activity of or the application, do the following:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
configuration.locale = new Locale("irn"); // or "off"
resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

This should do it.

Comment: This is what i exactly want, thanks buddy

Comment: @majidalamdari Would you please accept the answer and mark it as useful?

Answer (score 0):

if you have single message create two messages in string xml and set as per require and if there is array of message you can create string array in string xml and set it in widget as per user selection.

for ex.if user select official message you can fill up spinner with messages_array_of_official or else spinner fill with ironic_messages

Answer (score 0):

What i gather from your question is that you want multiple string values for the same name - String array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="message">
      <item>Ironic</item>
      <item>Official</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

To retrieve the string array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] msg = res.getStringArray(R.array.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch the meaning of the name of a string resource, but you could instead switch between sets of pre-built mappings of strings:

```
Resources res = getResources();

HashMap<Integer, String> ironic = new HashMap<Integer, String>()
ironic.put(R.string.official_hello, res.getString(R.string.ironic_hello);
ironic.put(R.string.official_goodbye, res.getString(R.string.ironic_goodbye);

HashMap<Integer, String> official = new HashMap<Integer, String>()
ironic.put(R.string.official_hello, res.getString(R.string.official_hello);
ironic.put(R.string.official_goodbye, res.getString(R.string.official_goodbye);
```

Now you can use the ironic version resource integers to look up into either ironic or official.  You just have to make a single choice (perhaps in your activity) to use the correct map and use that along with the official string resource ids to populate your TextView objects programmatically:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> strings;
if (is_ironic) {
    strings = ironic;
} else {
    strings = official;
}

TextView tv_hello = ...
tv_hello.setText(strings.get(R.string.official_hello));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-purpose Localization. There is many localization tutorial so I will only put in theory. Here is [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) and [some tutorial](https://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/)

Pros : Very clear code.

Cons : You may have to restart the app programmatically

Idea is by using non-ISO standard country code as Language for Ironic and Standard country code for Official.

You should create two folder in res like this:

> values (This one is official)
>
> values-rc (This one will be ironic)

And put in a string.xml in both folder.

> Official (values)

```
<resources>
    <string name="name">Official</string>
</resources>
```

> Ironic (values-rc)

```
<resources>
    <string name="name">Ironic</string>
</resources>
```

And you can change the selection by this code.

```
  public void updateCurrentContent(String currentContent) {
    try {
      Configuration config = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
      config.locale = new Locale(currentContent);
      getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

This way when user select Official, it will show get string from strings.xml under values and when user select Ironic, it will get string under values-rc.

This way you have a very clear structure. The only downside is you may have to restart the app for effect to take place.

You can restart activity with this code

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
intent.putExtra("from_setting", true);
getActivity().finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is a complete and useful answer , thanks